# Dropwizard - Setting a custom vary header

Tags: http, http-headers, jetty, dropwizard

I am having some trouble in setting a Vary header in the HTTP response of my dropwizard service.

I have a custom Filter configured that sets headers in the HTTP response, but dropwizard seems to override the value I set for the Vary header.

I currently have this:

1) A custom filter

```
environment.addFilter(CacheControlFilter.class, "/content/*");
```

2) This custom filter sets http headers

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
  resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age:180");
  resp.setHeader("Vary", "Accept");

}
```

While the Cache-Control header gets set as expected, setting the Vary headers seems to have no effect. Seems like something else is over-riding what I set later in the filter chain.

Any ideas what this could be and how I can set a Vary header of my choice?

I came across this which I think might have something to do with my issue, but not sure yet.
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was indeed due to the following issue:
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/494

As a temporary workaround, we disabled the gzip filter as we didn't really need it.